# How to change factor to binary numeric by a right answer?

Tags: r

```
q1  q2  q3
C   B   D
1   B   C
D   1   B
```

is a dataframe, columns `q1,q2,q3` are factors type with  4 levels `1,B,C,D`.

I would like to convert `B,C,D` to `0` means wrong answer, then I will get a numeric type dataframe only has `0 or 1`.

How to do it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a trick which makes this Vectorized,

```
 (df == 1)*1
 #or (df == 1)+0 , or even abs(df == 1) - as per @d.b's comment
```

which gives,

> ```
>      q1 q2 q3
> [1,]  0  0  0
> [2,]  1  0  0
> [3,]  0  1  0
> ```

To see how this works, `df == 1` creates a logical matrix. By multiplying the matrix by 1, we get the same effect as doing `as.integer()` (`TRUE * 1 = 1` and `FALSE * 1 = 0`) but this way it keeps the structure as a matrix, whereas `as.integer(df == 1)` converts to a vector (`[1] 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0`).

Comment: nice! at first I thought `1` here meant the 1st factor, but it works also when "1" is not the first factor, I don't understand why.

Comment: oh, probably the same reason why `"1" == 1` returns `TRUE`, `1` is coerced to `character`

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper I added some explanation

Comment: I had understood this part, it's just that I would have written it `(df == "1")*1` with `"1"` as a string. But I supposefactors are coerced to characters then numeric by `==` or the opposite.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper oh that. I never questioned it really so as to be able to give you an exact answer. Most likely what you said.

Comment: @d.b neat. I added that to the answer. Thanks - PS. No need to quote the numbers - Just had a talk with Moody about it

Comment: Again, to note, this converts the data.frame to a matrix. This conversion may be OK, and may even be preferable depending on what OP is doing next.

Answer (score 2):

I am not an expert in factor. However, if you read in your data frame as character, like the following example.

```
dt <- read.table(text = "q1  q2  q3
C   B   D
                 1   B   C
                 D   1   B ",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

You can consider the following, which will convert data frame to numeric with the binary outcomes.

```
dt[dt != "1"] <- "0"
dt <- as.data.frame(sapply(dt, as.numeric))

dt
  q1 q2 q3
1  0  0  0
2  1  0  0
3  0  1  0

str(dt)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ q1: num  0 1 0
 $ q2: num  0 0 1
 $ q3: num  0 0 0
```

#### Update

Solution from lmo. The use of `as.integer(x == "1")` is pretty nice, and `dt[] <- lapply(...)` is also a nice way to loop through all columns in a data frame.

```
dt[] <- lapply(dt, function(x) as.integer(x == "1"))
```

Comment: In one line: `dat[] <- lapply(dat, function(x) as.integer(x == "1"))`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! nice!

Comment: @lmo Would you like to submit your comment as an answer? I think this is a really nice and concise answer. Otherwise, with your permission, I can add your comment to my answer as an update.

Comment: @ycw You can add it to yours. They're pretty similar.

Answer (score 2):

Here are 2 ways:

```
df <- data.frame(q1 = factor(c("C","1","D"),levels=c("1","B","C","D")),
                 q2 = factor(c("B","B","1"),levels=c("1","B","C","D")),
                 q3 = factor(c("D","C","C"),levels=c("1","B","C","D")))

sapply(df,function(x){levels(x)[levels(x) %in% c("B","C","D")] <- 0;as.numeric(as.character(x))})

sapply(df,function(x){as.numeric(x=="1")})

#      q1 q2 q3
# [1,]  0  0  0
# [2,]  1  0  0
# [3,]  0  1  0
```